# Hartshorne Theorem 3.4: isomorphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, solution-verification

Let $Y\subseteq\mathbb{P}_k^n$ be a projective variety with homogeneous coordinate ring $S(Y)$.

I have to prove that the following map $J$ is an isomorphism. Define $J\colon k[y_1,\dots, y_n]\to k[x_0,\dots, x_n]_{(x_i)}$ by $$J(f(y_1,\dots, y_n)):=f\bigg(\frac{x_0}{x_i},\dots, \frac{x_{i-1}}{x_i}, \frac{x_{i+1}}{x_i},\cdots, \frac{x_n}{x_i}\bigg)$$

***Injectivity:***

Let $$f\bigg(\frac{x_0}{x_i},\dots, \frac{x_{i-1}}{x_i}, \frac{x_{i+1}}{x_i},\cdots, \frac{x_n}{x_i}\bigg)=g\bigg(\frac{x_0}{x_i},\dots, \frac{x_{i-1}}{x_i}, \frac{x_{i+1}}{x_i},\cdots, \frac{x_n}{x_i}\bigg)$$

Letting this element be of the form $s/x_i^e$ for some $s\in S(Y)_e$ and $e\ge 0$. we notice that $$x_i ^ef\bigg(\frac{x_0}{x_i},\dots, \frac{x_{i-1}}{x_i}, \frac{x_{i+1}}{x_i},\cdots, \frac{x_n}{x_i}\bigg)=x_i^e g\bigg(\frac{x_0}{x_i},\dots, \frac{x_{i-1}}{x_i}, \frac{x_{i+1}}{x_i},\cdots, \frac{x_n}{x_i}\bigg)$$ where both sides of the equality is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $e$. Now using the dehomogenization map we get $f=g$ in $k[y_1,\dots, y_n]$

***Surjectivity:***

Let $f(x_0,\dots,x_n)\in k[x_0,\dots, x_n]_{(x_i)}$, then $f(x_0,\dots, x_n)=s/x_i^m$, where $s\in S_m$, that is $s$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $m$. Then $$f(x_0\dots, x_n)=f\bigg(\frac{x_0}{x_i},\dots, \frac{x_{i-1}}{x_i}, \frac{x_{i+1}}{x_i},\cdots, \frac{x_n}{x_i}\bigg).$$

By placing $y_1=\frac{x_0}{x_i},\dots, y_n=\frac{x_n}{x_i}$ we have $$J(f(y_1,\dots, y_n)):=f\bigg(\frac{x_0}{x_i},\dots, \frac{x_{i-1}}{x_i}, \frac{x_{i+1}}{x_i},\cdots, \frac{x_n}{x_i}\bigg)=f(x_0,\dots, x_n)$$

It's correct? Thanks!

Comment: Only in the surjectivity: $J(s(y_1,\dots, y_n))=f.$

Comment: @EvansGambit Thanks, but I don't understand what you mean

Comment: If you calculate $J(s(y_1,\dots, y_n))= s(x_0/x_i, \dots, x_n/x_i)=x_i^{-m}s(x_0, \dots, x_n)$, where the last equality because $s$ is homogenous of degree $m$. The last term is exactly $f\in k[x_0, \dots, x_n]_{(x_i)}.$ On the other hand, try calculating $J(f)$.